# Pattern to handle list of derived class in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17

I have the following design problem. I have some base class `<BaseClass>` then I have many derived classes all executed in hierarchical order (if one returns something then stop loop), executing one method `checkSometching`

Here is code example:

X.hpp

```
class Base
{

public:
  virtual int checkSometching(int & i ) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived();
   int checkSometching(int & i);

protected:
  // some func/consts
};

int checkValue(int & i);
```

X.cpp:

```
Derived::Derived() {}

std::optional<int> Derived::checkSomething(int & i)
{
if(if i > 999){return 1;}

return {};

}

std::optional<int> checkValue(int & i)
{

  std::list<std::shared_ptr<Base>> derived_list;
  auto derived_obj = std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived());
  derived_list.push_back(derived_obj);

//... many derived

  for (const auto obj : derived_list) {
    auto res = obj->checkSomething(some_val);
    if (res) {return res;}  // Hierarchy matters so objects are added ordered.
  }
  return {};
}
```

So the final usage is to just call `checkValue()` but It seems to be unclear and complicated. Also note that in `checkValue()` all objects are created even if not used later! Do you guys have any idea how to solve this type of design problem? What is the appropriate pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve and I do not understand the problem. Maybe you can edit the question and explain better. `std::optional<int> Derived::checkSomething(int & i)` has a different signature than the definition in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Metaprogramming to the rescue!
Here we use variadic template function to iterate over a list of checkers, using fold expression:

```cpp
template<class TChecker>
std::optional<int> check_value_impl_impl(int & i)
{
    auto checker = TChecker();
    return checker.checkSometching(i);
}

template<class ... TCheckers>
std::optional<int> check_value_impl(int & i)
{
    std::optional<int> res;
    if ((((res = check_value_impl_impl<TCheckers>(i)) ? false : true) && ...))
        return {};
    return res;
}

std::optional<int> checkValue(int & i)
{
    return check_value_impl<Derived, Derived2>(i);
}
```

Also, don't forget about virtual destructors and consider refatoring `checkSomething` so that it actually performs a check (i.e. is `const` and returns `bool`).

Comment: Clever, thanks! The variadic template function is something that I can use. :D Unfortunately I can't vote you up but this concept helped me.